# cv::VideoCapture::set failed on image sequence

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use a cursor to seek a specific frame in stream.

*main.cpp* code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
  cv::VideoCapture cap;

  if (!cap.open("8%d.jpg"))
    return 1;

  double index = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);

  index += 10.0;    
  std::cout << "Seek to index: " << std::endl;

  if ( !(index < cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) )
    return 1;

  bool retval = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, index);
  assert(retval);

  std::cout << cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) << std::endl;

  cap.release();
  return 0;
}
```

Command line on Ubuntu 14.4.3 LTS with OpenCV 2.4.11:

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Command to check returning value:

```
echo "$#"
```

Output:

```
Seek to index: 10
-9.223377e+18
```

`cv::VideoCapture::set` function on an image sequence seems to break the stream, can you tell me why ?

Note: It works for a video as input but not an image sequence!

PS: I prefer asking before looking inside OpenCV-FFmpeg source code (it could take a while).

Comment: `It works for a video as input but not an image sequence!` - could you show how you use it with a video as input?

Comment: Of course, please replace image sequence name "8%d.jpg" by a valid video file name "video.mp4".